# Can't delete film from entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I seem to having a problem removing a Film from my database. I'm targeting the film using it's FilmId, however, when I try to delete I am prompted with the following error message.

The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Genres_dbo.Films_Film_FilmId"

I'm assuming this is because my Genre table has a relationship to the Film table, via the FilmId.

Here is my DeleteFilm method

```
public ActionResult DeleteFilm(int id)
{
    Film film = db.Films.Find(id);
    db.Films.Remove(film);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("MyFilms");
}
```

Here is the actionlink that calls this method

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Remove Movie", "DeleteFilm", new { id = Model.FilmId });
}
```

How would I delete the relationship in order for me to delete the film. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my Film class

```
public class Film
{
    [Key]
    public int FilmId { get; set; }
    public string FilmTitle { get; set; }
    public int FilmReleaseYear { get; set; }
    public string FilmDirector { get; set; }
    public string FilmRating { get; set; }
    public string FilmImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string FilmImdbUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Genre> FilmGenres { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FilmCastMember> FilmCastList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FilmReview> FilmReviews { get; set; }

    public Film()
    {
        FilmGenres = new List<Genre>();
        FilmCastList = new List<FilmCastMember>();
        FilmReviews = new List<FilmReview>();
    }
}
```

Here is my Genre type

```
public class Genre
{   
    [Key]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string GenreType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your Film and Genre types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guees that you need to have cascade delete in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a table sitting between the Films and Genres that defines their relationship?  You will probably need to query that table for all the records with the FilmID you are deleting and remove those records along with the actual Film record.

Looks like for Entity Framework code first you will need to override your OnModelCreating method on the DbContext.  Then you need to call the WillCascadeOnDelete method and pass it true.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Film>()
        .HasOptional(e => e.FilmGenres)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

You will probably find that you need to do a Migration to add this.

Alternatively, you could just call film.FilmGenres.Clear() to remove the Genres from the collection, but that will get tedious after awhile.

```
using (var db = new FilmContext())
{
    Film film = db.Films.First(each => each.FilmTitle == "Some Title");
    film.FilmGenres.Clear();
    db.Films.Remove(film);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Hi David, i'm new to mvc and databases. How would I check it there is a table sitting between the Film and Genre table? As far as I know they are connect directly via FilmId

Comment: "As far as I know they are connect directly via FilmId" - but there's no FilmId in the Genre table is there? There isn't in the class you've posted. And logically film-to-genre is a many-to-many relationship, which you usually represent as a join table with just film ID and genre ID columns. "How would I check" - can you connect to the database with SQL Server Management studio? I think there's a built-in database explorer in VS too.